# Add current date to mysql database in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have a my sql data base in which i have a field to store date. What I want to do is to store the current date to that field when i insert a new record.
My php code in Codeigniter to insert a new entry

```
$commentData = array(
            'comment'=>$message,
            'docid'=>$_GET['id'],
            'username'=>$owner,
            'commenter'=>$currentUser,
            //here i need to add my new date entry
        );

        $this->showSearchResult_model->addComment($commentData);
```

In my Model

```
$this->db->insert('comment', $comment);
```

How can I edit this to insert the current date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Native PHP:

```
'date_created' => Date("Y/m/d H:i:s"), //this is the default mysql formating for DATETIME
```

Or using codeigniter DB helpers, on your `showSearchResult_model` model in the `addComment()` method, right before you use the `$this->db->insert`

```
$this->db->set('date_creted','now()',false); //false is here to skip escaping
```

more info here: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Answer (score 1):

**Definition and Usage:**
`NOW()` returns the current date and time.

**Syntax:**

`NOW()`

**Example:**

The following `SELECT` statement:

`SELECT NOW(), CURDATE(), CURTIME()`
will result in something like this:

```
NOW()                 CURDATE()     CURTIME()   
2008-11-11 12:45:34   2008-11-11    12:45:34
```

**Example:**

The following `SQL` creates an `"Orders"` table with a `datetime` column (`OrderDate`):

```
CREATE TABLE Orders  
(  
OrderId int NOT NULL,
ProductName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
OrderDate datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
PRIMARY KEY (OrderId)
)
```

Notice that the `OrderDate` column specifies `NOW()` as the default value.
As a result, when you insert a row into the table, the current date and time are automatically inserted into the column.

Now we want to insert a record into the `"Orders"` table:

```
INSERT INTO Orders (ProductName) VALUES ('Jarlsberg Cheese')
```

The `"Orders"` table will now look something like this:

```
OrderId     ProductName         OrderDate  
1           Jarlsberg Cheese    2008-11-11 13:23:44.657
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `datecolumn` to be the name of the column where the date is stored:

```
$commentData = array(
    'comment'=>$message,
    'docid'=>$_GET['id'],
    'username'=>$owner,
    'commenter'=>$currentUser,
    'datecolumn'=>date('Y-m-d')
);
```

That is assuming you are using the `date` data type for that field. If it is actually a timestamp you would do this instead:

```
$commentData = array(
    'comment'=>$message,
    'docid'=>$_GET['id'],
    'username'=>$owner,
    'commenter'=>$currentUser,
    'datecolumn'=>time()
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you

```
 $commentData = array(
                'comment'=>$message,
                'docid'=>$_GET['id'],
                'username'=>$owner,
                'commenter'=>$currentUser,
                'date' => date("Y-m-d",time())
            );
```

Comment: it will take the current date and will set it to date index in array

Comment: The second parameter for `date()` is unecessary

Comment: Yup you can also use only `date("Y-m-d")` too.

Answer (score 0):

```
$commentData = array(
            'comment'=>$message,
            'docid'=>$_GET['id'],
            'username'=>$owner,
            'commenter'=>$currentUser,
            'date' => now()
        );`
```